# /home/~USER/public_html/django.fcgi/ was not found on this server

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

This is making me crazy. My .htaccess is

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And my django.fcgi looks ok

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ),'/home/USER/django-example-project/example_website'))
venv = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ),'/home/USER/django-example-project/venv/bin/activate_this.py'))
execfile(venv, dict(__file__=venv))
sys.path.insert(0, "{0}/../example_website".format(PROJECT_PATH))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "example_website.settings"
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

When I put in the browser `http://localhost/~USER` it gives me error

```
The requested URL /home/~USER/public_html/django.fcgi/ was not found on this server.
```

Why I am getting this error.
Both my .htacces and  django.fcgi are in public_html directory. I have tried many things but it always shows this :(